# what's the difference between pylint 'disable' and 'disable-msg'?

Tags: python, pylint

I see some code with

```
# pylint: disable=W0123
```

and some has

```
# pylint: disable-msg=W0123
```

Are they just synonyms?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

disable-msg is deprecated as of pylint 0.21.0. Update it to just "disable" when older versions don't need to be supported anymore.